# Button AND TextBox AND ComboBox Boarder 3D

Tags: vb.net, button, combobox, textbox, command

How can I make BOARDER tools like ***3D tools in Visual BASIC6*** ? And Is there a problem in the use of ***OLD Visual BASIC 6*** Tools??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a problem using old vb6 tools, it's the same problem as using pascal for vb.net application.

You can, however, draw a 3D border to just about any control in winforms, and I imagine that in wpf it's easier. check out ControlPaint class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint_methods(v=vs.110).aspx